# create subdomain using htaccess dynamically based on usernames

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a problem,
I need to know how to create a subdomain dynamically.

```
http://example.com/user.php?id=ajithjojo
```

I want it to work like

```
 http://ajithjojo.example.com/
```

how it's possible. I checked all of StackOverflow discussions but I didn't get a right answer what i need

Comment: Creating sub-domains is the job of a DNS server, not the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to implement some logic to add virtual hosts to the apache http server (complex and questionable) or you use a default host (one that responds to all incoming requests that are *not* handled by existing vhosts) and implement internal rewriting rules in that one. This allows you to simply hand out references to such "subdomains" (actually host names).

Those rewriting rules could look like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRUle ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?user=%1 [END]
```

Obviously you will need to adjust that to your actual setup, but it should point you into the right direction. For example you could use an implementation that evaluates the requested host instead of relying on a specific http get argument as shown above. But those are implementation details that you have to decide yourself.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: @Ajithjojo "not working" has never helped anyone anywhere at any time. You need to be specific. The approach certainly _does_ work, it is used on thousands of sites every single day. So the question is why it does not work for _you_ and also, obviously, how you have set up the approach. We cannot help further if you do not explain your problem and setup.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the htaccess.
You could setup your webserver so that *.example.com would point to a specific public root. In that public root resides a php script that checks the database to see if the host / username should exist.

So your first URL creates a record in the database that says that `ajithjojo` exists.
Then when visiting the second URL, the script sees that the domain exists and then does dynamic stuff.

If it does not exist the script throws a 404 header, or redirects somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Follow [this](https://www.9lessons.info/2016/03/how-to-create-dynamic-subdomains-using-php-and-htaccess.html) tutorial to set subdomains based on usernames